# formato pdf formData email

Tags: c#, angular, .net, smtp

Quiero enviar un pdf por email y le he pasado del angular a mi .NET a través de FormData.

Está es la línea que tengo para convertirlo y poder enviarlo pero me da error con todas las pruebas que hago.

```
        var pdf = HttpContext.Request.Form["filename"];
        var pdfBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(pdf);
        email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(pdfBinary), "pdf"));
```

no sé de que manera puedo mandarlo por email, este es mi codigo angular:

```
    sendEmail(to:string, subject:string, from:string, file:string){
  const headers = { 'content-type': '*' }
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('filename', file);

  const params = new HttpParams();
  params.append('to', to);
  params.append('subject', subject);
  params.append('from', from);

  return this.http.post(this.API_URL + 'Budgets/Send_Email?to='+to+'&subject='+subject+'&from='+from, formData, { headers: headers, params: params });
}
```

de momento me da error porque el archivo no puede empezar por x caracteres, que al parecer me da error con todos.

Un saludo.

Comment: Revisa está línea `Convert.FromBase64String(pdf)` Si se envía el archivo con `formData` no se convierte a base64.